# rails 4: how do I use url_for with a resource?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes

Migrating an app from Rails 2 to 4 because my server was hacked via the rails app, so I'm upgrading for security reasons. In my code I have this line:

```
lawyer_show_url = "<%= url_for(:controller => 'lawyers', :action => 'show') %>";
```

I now get this error message:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"lawyers"}):
```

In config/routes.rb, both with rails 2 and 4, I have this line:

```
resource :lawyers
```

My old config/routes.rb file also had the notorious catch-all:

```
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id'
map.connect ':controller/:action/:id.:format'
```

but I understand there's no place for code like that in rails 4.
How do I generate the URLs for my resources in rails 4?

Answer (score 0):

```
lawyer_url
```

Answer found in http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html ...